# JavaMail - setReplyTo (list)

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Using JavaMail I would do something like the following to send replayTo more one email.

I've tried creating an array and adding an address to the array. I can't just add the list as the setReplyTo takes a string

```
   message.setReplyTo( listOfAddresses)
```

I have the following:

```
            String[] mailAddressTo = new String[3];    
        String abb = user.getStoreAbbreviation();
        mailAddressTo[0] = abb + "test1@test.com" + ",";    
        mailAddressTo[1] = abb + "test2@test.com" + ",";    
        mailAddressTo[2] = abb + "test3@test.com";
        InternetAddress[] mailAddress_TO = new InternetAddress[mailAddressTo.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < mailAddressTo.length; i++) {
            mailAddress_TO[i] = new InternetAddress(mailAddressTo[i]);
        }
            MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);

        // this line worked fine   to use the replyTo message.setReplyTo(new InternetAddress("test@test.com"));
                         //same list worked fine for the seTo   message.setTo(mailAddressTo);
```

tried this,

```
message.setReplyTo(new InternetAddress[] 
                          {new InternetAddress(mailAddressTo)});
```

how could I pass the list?
Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is a limitation of MimeMessageHelper.  Try:

```
message.getMimeMessage().setReplyTo(mailAddress_TO);
```